# Error at line 7: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "/" - Oracle Live Tutorial

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex-5

I'm having issues with following the Oracle Live Apex tutorial at the following link:

https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/f?p=590:1:13286540921559:CLEAR::1:TUTORIAL_ID,P1_SHOW_LEARN_SIDEBAR:66403703756642340425947956952870068,Y

Specifically, it's for when I attempt to create triggers in my tables as part of that tutorial.  The code I copied and pasted into my Oracle Apex editor is the following:

```
create or replace trigger  DEPARTMENTS_BIU
    before insert or update on DEPARTMENTS
    for each row
begin
    if inserting and :new.deptno is null then
        :new.deptno := to_number(sys_guid(), 
          'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
    end if;
end;
/

create or replace trigger EMPLOYEES_BIU
    before insert or update on EMPLOYEES
    for each row
begin
    if inserting and :new.empno is null then
        :new.empno := to_number(sys_guid(), 
            'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
    end if;
end;
/
```

However, when I attempted to run the above code in Oracle Apex workspace, I get the error below:

Error at line 7: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "/"

However, when I run the same code in the Oracle Live SQL space (where the tutorial is located), the code runs fine. So how come I'm getting such an error in the Oracle APEX Workspace? It's just strange because I'm pretty sure the syntax is correct since I copied and pasted the code above from the Oracle Live tutorial.

For convenience, here is the code provided by the tutorial at the link above to create the necessary tables:

DEPARTMENTS table

```
create table DEPARTMENTS (  
  deptno        number,  
  name          varchar2(50) not null,  
  location      varchar2(50),  
  constraint pk_departments primary key (deptno)  
);
```

EMPLOYEES table

```
create table EMPLOYEES (  
  empno             number,  
  name              varchar2(50) not null,  
  job               varchar2(50),  
  manager           number,  
  hiredate          date,  
  salary            number(7,2),  
  commission        number(7,2),  
  deptno           number,  
  constraint pk_employees primary key (empno),  
  constraint fk_employees_deptno foreign key (deptno) 
      references DEPARTMENTS (deptno)  
);
```

I also went further into the tutorial, only to run into similar  errors in Oracle Apex Workspace i.e. ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended when running the following code:

```
insert into departments (name, location) values
   ('Finance','New York');

insert into departments (name, location) values
   ('Development','San Jose');
```

I think the tutorial at the link above is outdated due to the fact that the Oracle Apex Workspace has just updated its version and some of the tutorial's codes no longer work, but that may not be the case.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: See here -https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12004.htm IDK anything about apex, but my guess is that apex workspace executes single statements?  run each statement separately, and see

Comment: @OldProgrammer I have tried that and that worked, Thanks!  Apparently the workspace's SQL Commands section of the SQL workshop can only take single statements at a time, which really sucks because it can be tedious having to execute one statement at a time.

Comment: glad it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Using Apex, if you want to create several tables (or triggers, functions, procedures, views etc), use *SQL Scripts* - see the screen shots below.

{1} Script editor (with your CREATE TABLE and CREATE TRIGGER statements)

[image]

Type in all the code, and then "Run" the script.  Check the output, and amend the script if need be.

{2} output

[image]

If you  make changes to the tables' DDL code (and then run the script again),  you'll probably get error messages - as the tables already exist.  In this case, you can add a line DROP TABLE ... CASCADE CONSTRAINTS; for each table at the start of the script.  (Use this with caution though, as this will DROP the tables, even if they contain data!)

For INSERTs, you can either create another SQL Script (or indeed add all the INSERTS to the script that contains the CREATE TABLE statements), or you can use SQL Commands, and run single INSERTs (by highlighting them, and clicking the Run button).  You can also run several INSERTs by using SQL Commands and writing BEGIN and END; before and after the INSERTs, respectively - see the examples below.

{SQL Commands, single INSERT: highlight and Run}

[image]

{SQL Commands, multiple INSERTS}

[image]

Notice that there is a "History" tab (in the SQL Commands window).  This can be really useful eg it can save you a lot of typing etc.